# I am unable to update my C# string variable

Tags: c#, winforms

New to C#. I am trying to create a WinForms application to run different batch files. Due to the different path of the batch files for everyone (depending on where they store it), I am planning to let user select their path when they first start the WinForms.
I have tried several ways to save the path into a variable, then plan to use the variable to with Process.Start

Below are a part of my codes:

```
private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    string filePath = "a";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        labelTest.Text = filePath;
        Properties.Settings.Default["filePath"] = filePath;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

I'm constantly receiving an error in my if statement, `cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`.

May I know what am I doing wrong? Appreciate any advices!

Comment: Why are you declaring `filePath` both outside and inside the `if` block? Do you think you need two variables with the same name? Given that you don't use the variable outside the `if` block at all, don't declare it outside the `if` block. That way, declaring it inside the `if` block, where you actually want to use it, won't be an issue.

Comment: You can't have two variables called `filePath` in the same method. I assume you want your second statement to change the existing variable. eg `filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;`

Comment: Also, don't use `Properties.Settings.Default["filePath"]`. Use `Properties.Settings.Default.filePath`. Create the setting with an appropriate property name in the first place though, i.e. `FilePath`.

Comment: @John Thank you for the advices, appreciate it. I'm trying to do something like if the filePath variable is empty, then run the OpenFileDialog codes to retrieve the path, otherwise, else, run the Process.Start codes with the filePath as the parameter. Is that feasible? Once again, thank you!

Comment: *"if the filePath variable is empty"*. Read those words. That's basically psuedo-code. Can you think of a way to implement that in code?

Comment: @John I don't think so, but will there be a way to do something like if filePath is not null, then run another block of codes which is basically Process.Start codes? Because for now, I am unable to access even the filePath variable. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Two people have already told you why the issue relating to your variable occurs and how to fix it. Once you have fixed it, the rest is simply writing an `if` statement, which you already know how to do.

Comment: When you get a compiler error, you should search the error code first, i.e. `CS0136`, in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com). If you are using Visual Studio, just click on the error link and you will be directed to corresponding page, e.g. [CS0136](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136) .